# VSTO Word Addin: set_Style(ref code), ignoring background color

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto, office-addins

When I try to set the **style** of a selection to code-style with:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWordApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection currentSelection = oWordApp.Selection;

object codeStyle = "Code";
// this disrespects the background
currentSelection.set_Style(ref codeStyle);
```

It ignores the background-color (lightblue):

[image]

When I apply it to the **Range**, it does it for the whole paragraph:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWordApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection currentSelection = oWordApp.Selection;

// this sets the style to the whole paragraph, but i want the range only
currentSelection.Range.set_Style(ref codeStyle);
```

[image]

Defined "Code" is:

[image]

**I only want the word/selection "attacker" in code-style.** What am I doing wrong? When i recorded a macro it gave me this:

```
Selection.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Code")
```

but this doesn't help me much...

Comment: Could you please use the [edit] link below the question to include information on the style's *definition*? Also, is this a character style, a paragraph style or a linked style type?

Comment: I can't repro, but... What is the `Range` object? A selection? A paragraph...? And what formatting does this range have before the style is applied?

Comment: Thanks for asking. i have diffrent problems either it is a selection or a paragraph... see above. I edited my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. You can append the style base after a sytle:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application oWordApp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("Word.Application");
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Selection currentSelection = oWordApp.Selection;

object codeStyle = "Code Char"; //appending Char made its job!
currentSelection.Range.set_Style(ref codeStyle);
```